# Why or when does npm sometimes allows conflicts with a warn (`overriding peer dependency`) instead of an error (`could not resolve`)?

Tags: npm, npm-install, peer-dependencies

Tl;dr: `overriding peer dependency` vs `could not resolve` in npm.

---

Since npm 7, npm no longer allows installing with peer dependencies conflicts,
so errors like this are expected:

```js
npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
npm ERR! ERESOLVE could not resolve
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! While resolving: ___@x.x.x
```

But I've also seen non blocking peer dependencies resolution conflicts,
that result in a simple `WARN` instead of `ERR!`,
and npm is happy to override the conflicting requirement:

```js
npm WARN ERESOLVE overriding peer dependency
npm WARN While resolving: airbnb-prop-types@2.16.0
npm WARN Found: react@17.0.2
npm WARN node_modules/react
npm WARN   peer react@">=16" from ___@x.x.x
npm WARN   node_modules/___
npm WARN     ___@"^x.x.x" from the root project
npm WARN   42 more (___, ___, ___, ...)
npm WARN 
npm WARN Could not resolve dependency:
npm WARN peer react@"^0.14 || ^15.0.0 || ^16.0.0-alpha" from airbnb-prop-types@2.16.0
npm WARN node_modules/airbnb-prop-types
npm WARN   airbnb-prop-types@"^2.8.1" from react-dates@12.7.1
npm WARN   node_modules/react-dates
npm WARN 
npm WARN Conflicting peer dependency: react@16.14.0
npm WARN node_modules/react
npm WARN   peer react@"^0.14 || ^15.0.0 || ^16.0.0-alpha" from airbnb-prop-types@2.16.0
npm WARN   node_modules/airbnb-prop-types
npm WARN     airbnb-prop-types@"^2.8.1" from react-dates@12.7.1
npm WARN     node_modules/react-dates
```

Do you know in which case npm overrides instead of failing?
Is there documentation on the subject?

(And is there a way, as a library author to relax a peer dependency so that it can be overridden?)

Answer (score 0):

The project installing a dep with conflicting peerDeps can force installation of the specific conflicting dependency with the `overrides` section of the `package.json`:
https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v10/configuring-npm/package-json#overrides

This is better than `legacy-peer-deps`, as it's fine-grained and explicitly lists which peerDep constraints are overridden instead of being an open bar of conflicts.

Example:

```json
   "overrides": {
    "react": "^17.0.2"
   }
```

or better:

```json
   "overrides": {
    "react": "$react"
   }
```

so the override is kept in sync with the local dependency.